# SFML C++ getSize() and sprite.move() in SFML.net

Tags: c#, c++, sfml, sfml.net

My first question is if C++:

```
pTexture.getSize().x
```

equals C# (because this is no result for me using this):

```
pTexture.Size().X
```

Second question is about C++ code (how to write in SFML.net this line).

```
pImage.move(0,-1)
```

pImage is Sprite and pTexture is Texture of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SFML.NET there is no getter/setter methods for properties, so in order to get/set the size you have to :

```
texture.Size = // ...
myfunction(texture.Size);
```

As there is no setter method, you have to use `+=` on the `Position` property to simulate the `move` method.